# How to center a GameObject between a LineRenderer and an empty GameObject dynamically in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, centering

I'm generating a `playerController` dynamically through a server (each time someone connects). My problem is being able to center it in the X axis, using as references both an `EmptyGameObject` and a `LineRenderer` element.

Here's how it is looking

[image: screenshot]

I need that rectangle to update it position each time either of those 2 elements moves, so it's always X-centered between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your problem correctly, but I assume that to get correct X value you need to do this:

```
float targetXposition = 
    ((lineStartPoint.x + lineEndPoint.x) / 2f + emptyGameObject.position.x) / 2f;
```

Then apply new X position to your rectangle like this

```
Vector3 position = transform.position
transform.position = new Vector3(targetXposition, position.y, position.z);
```

Also don't forget to get fresh values of your `LineRenderer`'s start and end points.

Comment: https://goo.gl/Ie63fD. Thank you for your kind reply. Is it something like this what you meant? Not working..

Comment: Not really. Your line (drawn by LineRenderer component) placed not in the same place with gameObject, to which LineRenderer is attached. Somewhere in the code you call lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, position) to set line's start and end points. So you also need to pass this points to your rectangle object so he can know where your line is, not line's gameObject.

Comment: https://goo.gl/iYY0k0. I'm getting an error at line 22: Unexpected symbol ')', expecting ';'. Could this be because of the way I'm grabbing the anchor "Left"?

Comment: https://goo.gl/sMyZEm. Still the same error in the same line.. :s what am I missing?

Comment: Oh, we have one redundant ")" in the end of 23th line. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: Ok, so, after I fixed that  extra ')', I had another error. I fixed it and now I'm having another one, but I'm not managing.. Here's what happens when I run it: https://goo.gl/X3yatJ

Comment: Check that you have GameObjects with names "Origin", "Destination" and "Left" on all of them are enabled in project's hierarchy.

Comment: Two of them were not enlabled. I just check them and the error is gone. But although the console is bugless, it doesn't work, the objects position doesn't update when I change the line..

Comment: On line 26 change "Vector" to "Vector3"